# Update all recored below current record given by id

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-update

HI i want to update all records in my table when i am having an id of a specific record with the following sql:

```
Update table1 SET field2 = field2 + 1 Where id = 129;
Update table1 SET field2 = field2 -1 where feild2 > (SELECT feild2 from table1 WHERE id = 129);
```

But MYSQL says  You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause

Is there a way to update like feild on same table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this one by giving new alias to your subquery

```
Update table1 SET field2 = field2 -1 where feild2 > 
(SELECT t.feild2 FROM 
(SELECT feild2 from table1 WHERE id = 129) 
t)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SET @var =(SELECT feild2 from table1 WHERE id = 129);
Update table1 SET field2 = field2 -1 where feild2 > @var;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT  feild2 from table1 
WHERE id = 129
```

run above query 1st, then use output of this in your main query in 'where' clause.

Answer (score 0):

to avoid *"You can't specify target table 'table1' for update in FROM clause"*, you would use JOIN. like this:

```
Update table1 t1, table2 t2
SET t2.field2 = t2.field2 -1
where t2.feild2 > t1.feild2 
AND t1.id = 129;
```

you're query looks like this:

```
Update table1 SET field2 = field2 -1
       ^^^^^^ <= table1 is here.
where feild2 > (SELECT feild2 from table1 WHERE id = 129);
                                   ^^^^^^ <= but table1 can't be used here.
```

Comment: if this can be helpful using both same table